# Hibernate (SpringBoot JPA) invert save sequence

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm using `SpringBoot 2.2.6` with `JPA` and I'm run into following problem:

```
@Transactional
public void batch() {
....
....
repository.save(data) // this is an update
....
....
repository.save(data) // this is a normal save

}
```

the `Hibernate` logging says to me that the `save` is executed before the `update` and this generate a constraint violation error on my db.

Do you have some idea why happend something like this?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

The `Entity` is something like this, clearly there are other `Entity` nested but the logic is similar

```
@Id
@Column(name="id")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "domande_dom_stati_domanda_id_seq", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "domande_dom_stati_domanda_id_seq", sequenceName = "domande_dom_stati_domanda_id_seq",allocationSize=1)
private Integer id;

@Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id_dom_stato_domanda", nullable=false)
private DomStatoDomanda domandaStatoDomanda;

@Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id_domanda", nullable=false)
private Domanda domande;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="data_validita")
private Date dataValidita;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="data_registrazione")
private Date dataRegistrazione;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="data_registrazione_fine")
private Date dataRegistrazioneFine;

@Column(length=50)
private String utente;

@Column(length=250)
private String note;

@Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id_ruolo", nullable=false)
private Ruolo ruolo;
```

Comment: Please show the Entity you are saving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `JPA`/`Hibernate` queues the operations in its `session` whenever possible, does not call the database instantly and then just before the transaction is completing, order those operations based on type and execute them.  This is called `Transactional write-behind` in hibernate. As you can see, even though you called the insert last, hibernate will order it as first if it was queued.

  1. Inserts, in the order they were performed
  2. Updates
  3. Deletion of collection elements
  4. Insertion of collection elements
  5. Deletes, in the order they were performed
- You can tell hibernate to flush it rather than queue it. So replace `repository.save(data)` with `repository.saveAndFlush(data)` so it executes in the order you wanted

**Reference**

- [Executions Order](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/event/internal/AbstractFlushingEventListener.html#performExecutions-org.hibernate.event.spi.EventSource-)

Comment: You are the best!! I will try your solution and let you know! THANKS

Comment: Yes man sorry for the late but I have to wait the batch execution! It solve the issue!